# C# WinForms - Looping through all controls to apply event handler, not working in SplitContainer?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, controls

I've got these functions:

```
    private void setupFocusControls(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
        {
            control.GotFocus += HandleFocus;
        }
    }

    private void HandleFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = (Control)sender;
        thisFormName = this.Name;
        thisControlName = control.Name.ToString();


        if (bHelpSystemActive)
        {
            bHelpSystemActive = false;

            if ((ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)
            {
                HelpSystem hs = new HelpSystem(thisFormName, thisControlName);
                hs.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                showTooltipForControl(control, thisFormName);
            }


            return;
        }
    }
```

And I call this in the Form_Load function:

```
    private void Labeller_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setupFocusControls(this);
        fillListBox();
    }
```

What this does is show a custom help system I've written. If no control key is clicked, then I'll display the info in a tool tip. If the control key is pressed, then I show an editor. Simple really.

Now, this code works perfectly on another form, which uses panels as containers for my form controls. The problem is, I now want to add this functionality to a separate form. I've added all the code, but none of the controls on the form are having the HandleFocus event added to them. The only difference between this form and the working one is that it uses a splitContainer as it's container.

My question is, why is the `setupFocusControls` function not looping through the splitContainer as it does the panels on my working form? And, how would I go about fixing it? I'd obviously rather not have several functions to perform this (what I thought) simple task...

Cheers.

Comment: Do you want _every_ control on the form to have the event? Or just top-level ones? If you want every control, then you need to use recursion to assign the event to each control.

Comment: Can you show your `OnLoad` code for the split container form please?

Comment: Yes, every control needs to have this event, as my help system is configured on a per-control basis. i.e. detailing each and every control and what it's for. How would I go about doing that? I've got 50+ controls on the other form and it works perfectly using the above method. I thought it would apply nicely :(

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you, you're a star! :) I like easy fixes.

Comment: I'll accept when the timer ticks over :) Cheers again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the problem is that you are not assigning the event to *every* single control on the form (only top-level controls), the fix should be to change your `setupFocusControls(Control)` method:

```
private void setupFocusControls(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
    {
        control.GotFocus += HandleFocus;
        // add the following line to recurse throughout the control tree
        setupFocusControls(control);
    }
}
```

This will add the `HandleFocus` event handler to *every* single control, by recursing through the children of every control. I hope this works for you!

As a bonus, if you want to add the event handler to all controls, *including* the `parent` control, you could write the `setupFocusControls` method as follows:

```
private void setupFocusControls(Control parent)
{
    parent.GotFocus += HandleFocus;
    foreach (Control child in parent.Children)
        setupFocusControls(child);
}
```